# What happens to batteries connected together with a resistor?

Tags: physics

I have 2 batteries, one is 5V, the other is 1V. I connect the batteries positive to positive and negative to negative. Further more I add a resistor in between the positive and negative leads.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyv7KA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then what happens?

One thing would be current rushing from the 5V battery into the 1V one possibly destroying it but that's just a poor setup for the thing I'm interested in, what happens to the resistor? Does it get 5V? or 1V? Or both? Logic would suggest the resistor would get 4V but I tried it in a circuit simulator and it failed to analyze the situation and I can't make Google understand what I'm asking.

Comment: NEVER reccommend this, but different results will be expected using different parts. Are the batteries same in technology (i.e. regular, rechargable, LiOn, etc)? Are they same in capacity and size? What is the magnitude of the external resistor? A short answer anyway is that if external resistor is much higher than the internal resistance of batteries (i.e 0.1Ω), then ignored.

Comment: @NickAlexeev no, it won't. Read carefully: the question is about parallel batteries, not series batteries: "positive to positive and negative to negative".

Comment: Unfortunately, you accepted an answer that incorrectly interpreted your question and is therefore incorrect itself. By the way, the circuit drawn by Phil Frost can never be simulated, it is an invalid, nonsensical circuit. You cannot connect two voltage sources in parallel if they have different voltages. That's not a reflection on Phil Frost, he drew it as you described it.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming we are talking about the circuit below:

[image: Described circuit with ideal batteries]

...then the voltage across the resistor is indeterminate. If we assume the batteries are mathematically ideal voltage sources, then the circuit is like saying 5 = 1. It can't be solved because it's inconsistent to begin with.

Just because ideal batteries create a mathematical problem doesn't mean building the circuit with real batteries breaks any physics (but it will quickly break the batteries themselves, wire used to connect them, and/or the experimenter). Actual batteries and the wire used connect them have some a small but nonzero series resistance. If we model the internal resistances of the batteries then the circuit to analyze looks like this:

[image: Batteries with internal resistance]

For a typical battery, R1 and R2 will be under an ohm. The series resistance makes the circuit solvable.

Answer (score 7):

The resistor can't get "both" 5V and 1V. It can get only one voltage. It's a basic property of the [lumped element model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumped_element_model) that the potential at any node is the same everywhere in that node. Your circuit has two nodes: one is the positive terminals and one side of the resistor. The other node is the negative terminals and the other side of the resistor.

Since a voltage is a difference in potentials, and you have only two nodes, and thus two potentials, there can be only *one* voltage in this circuit: the difference in potential between the two nodes.

Simultaneously, you have two batteries, which are devices that ideally maintain a constant voltage between two nodes. You have two batteries connected to the same two nodes trying to maintain a different potential difference between those nodes, but circuit analysis dictates each node can only have one potential. You have an impossible situation, and this is why your simulator can't find a result.

You can't ask what happens to the resistor, because the situation you have described can't happen. If you were able to construct this circuit with ideal components, the universe would implode. There is a 4V difference between the batteries, connected by a resistance of 0Ω. By Ohm's law, the current would be:

$$ \frac{4V}{0\Omega} = $$

[image: divide by zero]

Alternately, you could say as the resistance between the batteries approaches 0Ω, then the current approaches \$\infty A\$. As that happens, power, the product of current and voltage also approaches infinity. If power is the rate of energy consumption, then as resistance approaches zero, you approach using infinite energy infinitely fast, which again would likely result in the universe implosion pictured above. If you like math:

$$ P = \lim_{R \searrow 0\Omega} \frac{4V}{R} \cdot 4V = \infty W $$

The reason why the universe isn't actually destroyed is that the batteries and the wires used to connect them actually have some small resistance, so R can't go all the way to 0Ω, but that's not in your model. Circuit analysis is accurate only to the extent that the model is accurate. In most cases, the resistance of the wire and batteries is so small compared to everything else it's not significant, so we simplify our model. This is not one of those cases.

Comment: Does someone want to explain the downvote?

Answer (score -4):

See it's just simple !!!! Two parallel batteries will act as a single battery of  5r+1R (assumed that u have given the initial P.D. Of the batteries).however if internal resistances are same then the question is flawed.but assuming that I.R. are same u can also use Kirchhoff laws also.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, @Messi. Your answer is short on detail and shows some confused thinking. What is a battery of "5r+1R". (and what is little 'r' and big 'R')? What do you mean by "if internal resistances are the same"? You need to edit (and add capital letters and spacing where they're required to improve the legibility.

Comment: @Messi, Also, please avoid using abbreviation for simple words such as 'you' nor for uncommon technical terms such as 'potential drop'.